# Jenkins SSH plugins issue

Tags: jenkins

Could some one help me on these questions
1) I need a files to be transfered from build machine to some remote machine, IM using Jenkins to build the projects.I installed SSH plugins but it says "Cant connect to server".

Do i need to run the server on my remote machine for this ? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Your remote-server needs to run a ssh-server, yes.

Comment: please let me know the configuration part of it.